# Can we use Azure DevOps Test Plans for Datalake testing

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm working on a Data Lake project and I'm using Azure Databricks (writing pyspark code) for ETL purpose and Azure DevOps for CICD and source control purpose. I have noticed Test Plans n Devops: my query is can I use test plans for Data Lake testing? I went through the internet browsing related test plans but I did not find anything about plans related to Data Lake, Database or Data warehousing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Devops Test Plans for Datalake testing. If your Data Lake test cases are written in c#, you can use Azure devops Test plans for Datalake testing just like any other c# test projects.

1,Here is the example for set up Datalake test case, [Test your Azure Data Lake Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-cicd-test) code.

2,Then you can [create test workitems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#add-a-work-item) in your azure devops boards.

3,After your test items are created in azure devops, you can associate them to your test cases in visual studio test project. Please check the detailed steps 
[Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops).

4, In the **Test plans** of your azure devops project, [Create test plans for your test work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops#create-a-test-plan)

5, Then you can [run your automated tests from the test hub in azure devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I'm going to write test cases either sql or python. I'm not using c#